# IntelliJ IDEA debugger for Java: return desirable value from method during debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

In Eclipse there is feature "Force return" which allows to return any selected object from method call. 
Is there such feature in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, there is. This feature was introduced in IntelliJ IDEA 15. When debugging, open the debugger window, select the frames tab (beside threads) then right click on a frame/method in the list and select "Force Return" and supply the value.

Comment: Note that you first need to be inside a method in order to see it in the frames tab.